# Python pandas filter by column name and drop column if inferior as reference column value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop all column that contain PP in the name if their values are inferior or equal to the column 'price'.

I think need to exclude the highPrice column and lowPrice column because they does not contain PP.
and use something like this:

```
df = df[df.filter <= df.price]
```

but i dont know how to do the filter thing and how to include it.

Here is my df:

```
price   highPrice     lowPrice     PP_1     PP_2     PP_3     PP_4    PP_5     PP_6     PP_7
  1.1         1.2          1.0      0.1      0.2     0.3       0.8     1.1      1.5      2.2
```

my expected result is:

```
price   highPrice     lowPrice     PP_5     PP_6     PP_7
  1.1         1.2          1.0      1.1      1.5      2.2
```

Comment: What if some values are  higher than price and some are  lower  in a PP column ? Do you want include or exclude it ?

Comment: I don't get if you wanna drop the whole columns or just the rows?

Comment: I want to drop the whole columns

Comment: values in all PP colums will always be same in all rows

Comment: In DataFrame is only one or multiple rows?

Comment: df is 1 row only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter columns with `PP` for greter or equal like `lowPrice` by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), get all missing columns with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and filter columns by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[:, df.filter(like='PP').ge(df['lowPrice'], axis=0).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=True, axis=1)]
print (df)
   price  highPrice  lowPrice  PP_5  PP_6  PP_7
0    1.1        1.2       1.0   1.1   1.5   2.2
```